# Auto-mock container: Rhino Mocks and NInject

Tags: rhino-mocks, ninject

Does anyone have an implementation lying around of an auto-mock container using Rhino Mocks and NInject?

Comment: I know it should be all obvious and that but... What features are you looking for ? Any more context you can share?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK I built one myself using the Moq integration as a starting point. It is very simple. You need these 3 classes:

```
public class AutoMockingKernel : StandardKernel
{
    private readonly IMockProvider _mockProvider;

    public void Reset()
    {
        Components.Get<ICache>().Clear();
    }

    protected override bool HandleMissingBinding(Type service)
    {
        var isSelfBindable = TypeIsSelfBindable(service);

        var binding = new Binding(service)
        {
            ProviderCallback = isSelfBindable
                                ? StandardProvider.GetCreationCallback(service)
                                : _mockProvider.GetCreationCallback(),
            IsImplicit = true
        };

        if (!isSelfBindable)
            binding.ScopeCallback = ctx => null;

        AddBinding(binding);

        return true;
    }

    public AutoMockingKernel(IMockProvider mockProvider, INinjectSettings settings, params INinjectModule[] modules)
        : base(settings, modules)
    {
        _mockProvider = mockProvider;
    }

    public AutoMockingKernel(IMockProvider mockProvider, params INinjectModule[] modules)
        : base(modules)
    {
        _mockProvider = mockProvider;
    }
}

internal class RhinoMockProvider : IProvider
{
    public Type Type { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RhinoMockProvider"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public RhinoMockProvider(Type type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    public object Create(IContext context)
    {
        return MockRepository.GenerateMock(Type, Type.EmptyTypes);
    }
}

public class RhinoAutoMockProvider : IMockProvider
{
    public Func<IContext, IProvider> GetCreationCallback()
    {
        return ctx => new RhinoMockProvider(ctx.Request.Service);
    }
}
```

You can then create an auto-mocking kernel in your unit test like this:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var kernel = new AutoMockingKernel(new RhinoAutoMockProvider());
    ... etc
}
```

Comment: As a matter of interest, how do you manage triggering of Reset, in [Teardown] ?

Comment: I use a base class for all my test fixtures which calls Reset during teardown. I also use a static kernel container. Definitely not ideal, but I find this sort of stuff never is.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [RhinoMocks integration extension available](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.mockingkernel).